# Chat app architecture in android

Tags: android

I want to develop a chat app in android. I have to use node.js for delivering messages in app also I have to use gcm for push notifications (if user is not online and someone has sent a message to user I have to send a push notification to receiver)

**My architecture:**

User A sent a message to User B:

1. Send this message to node.js server
2. Node.js server takes the message and receiver
3. Then node.js server looks to database for receiver's online status
4. If receiver is not online node.js server will do a http request to gcm server for push notification.
5. If receiver is online node.js server sends the message to receiver using socket system.

But there is a problem with my algorithm. In each message node.js will look the database for online status. I think this is a not good for server.

What do you suggest? How can I handle this?

Comment: why do you think it is not good for the server? What's the point of the isOnline field if you're not going to check against it from your database?

Comment: This app will use by many people.(Estimated concurrent 1000 users.) I think database load will be problem for us.

Comment: You're underestimating the performance of servers and databases. In this context, 1000 users is a small number.

Comment: Did you develop a chat app before ? I am asking for ask example numbers.I am inexperienced about this context